# Need help starting a proof

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I'm not too sure where to start with this proof and just need some pointers on how to approach this.

∀a, b ∈ Z,    $a^2 + b^2 − 3 \not\equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 4)$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What could $a^2\pmod4$ be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a$ is even, then $a^2\equiv0\pmod4$.

If $a$ is odd, then $a^2\equiv1\pmod4$.

Same with $b$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think i found the approach, would it turn out to be a proof by cases then?

Comment: yes, it could be a proof by cases